# Grooviest way to clean malformed json in memory

Tags: json, groovy

Working with some json files, ran into some malformed ones with c style comments included.  Assume I don't have ownership of these files, and changing them is not an option, I need to analyze the json data in an automated fashion.  JsonSlurper dies when it sees these comments, so I wrote a method to remove the offending lines:

```
def filterComments(String raw){
    def filtered = ""
    raw.eachLine { line ->
        def tl = line.trim()
        if(!(tl.startsWith("//") || tl.startsWith("/**") || tl.startsWith("*"))){
            filtered += line;}}
    return filtered;
}
```

I really like Groovy and have turned to it as my maintenance tool of choice, but am not the "Grooviest" developer, this is an example.  I would like a more Groovy way of accomplishing this.

Some additional notes: this is run as a script.  If there is a way to make JsonSlurper disregard the comments instead of using this utility method, that solution would be considered more valuable.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def json = '''
// A comment
Foo f = new Foo(); // this is a comment
/*
* Multiline comment
*
*/
'''

def filterComments(str) {
    str?.replaceAll(/(\/\/|\/\*|\*).*\n?/, '')?.trim()
}

assert filterComments(json) == 'Foo f = new Foo();'
```

This will remove any line that begins with `/*` or `*`, as well as anything after `//`.

Answer (score 3):

My take:

```
def filterComments(str){
    str.readLines().findAll{ !(it ==~ /^\s*(\*|\/\*\*|\/\/).*/) }.join('\n')
}
```

Comment: This does not filter any of the comments for me.

Comment: Works better, but misses /*

Comment: Changing the regex to `/^\s*(\*|\/\*|\/\/` should pick up `/*`. So the line would be `str.readLines().findAll{ !(it ==~ /^\s*(\*|\/\*|\/\/).*/) }.join('\n')`

Comment: @md_rasler It misses `/*` only because your code would miss it too.. I only rephrased your code ;-)